# Could Elasticsearch hot reload log4j2.properties?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j2

I have a production elasticsearch used log4j that is vulnerable

```
./lib/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar
./lib/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar
```

because it's a production environment, I do not want to reboot it, I saw somebody said could hot reload it in the below manner

```
 you can still mitigate it in those cases by replacing %m, %msg, and %message in log4j2.xml with %m{nolookups} instead
```

In my case it uses log4j2.properties, there is one line as below

```
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] [%node_name]%marker %m%n
```

whether modify this line like below

```
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] [%node_name]%marker %m{nolookups}%n
```

and it can take effect automatically without the need to reboot explicitly?

Comment: I don't think so, you will ned to restart the service, also, to mitigate the Log4Shell vulnerability the recommended way is to use a `.options` file with the config `-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true`. You can read more about it in this [security announcement](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/apache-log4j2-remote-code-execution-rce-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228-esa-2021-31/291476/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4j2 does not have a file watcher that enables hot reaload of configurations per default. You must still restart your server in order to apply the new pattern.